# She wasn't expecting a call or she weren't expecting a call?

Tags: word-choice

> Cindy said that she would accompany me to the party with pleasure if she **wasn’t** expecting a call from her parents that night.
>
> Cindy said that she would accompany me to the party with pleasure if she **weren't** expecting a call from her parents that night.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The sentence reads better like _Cindy said that she would have accompanied me to the party with pleasure had she not been expecting a call from her parents that night._

Answer (score 2):

The answer is either. The "if she weren't expecting" is the more traditional with the use of the past subjunctive to indicate a contrary to fact situation (she actually is expecting a call).

More modern use tends to replace the subjunctive verb forms with the corresponding indicative, thus "if she wasn't expecting"

Answer (score 0):

Cindy said, "I will accompany you to the party with pleasure if I am not expecting a call from my parents this night".

This sentence is in direct speech.  In other words, the reporting clause is in the past, and that-clause is in the present tense and indicative mood, not in the subjunctive mood.  The sentence in indirect speech is as follows:

Cindy said that she would accompany me to the party with pleasure if she was not expecting a call from her parents that night.

So we should use the "was" instead of the subjunctive "were" in the sentence.

Comment: In direct speech, Cindy wouldn't say "she" nor "accompany me". Secondly, your direct speech version is only one possibility. Your version is possible if at the time of speaking Cindy didn't know whether she would be expecting a call at the time of the party. If however she knew at the time of speaking she was expecting a call, then she would have said "I would accompany you... if I weren't expecting a call" and thus the reported speech form is either of the above.

Comment: It's also rather odd to back-shift conditionals and make them not irrealis, as you suggest because after an event has happened, it's no longer conditional. The past is known.

Comment: @eques, Thanks for pointing out mistakes in the direct speech. I have edited  it.